# Unfounded sound changes

Tags: historical-linguistics

For example can a voiced pharyngeal fricative  [ʕ] develop into the Voiceless bilabial fricative ⟨ɸ⟩? Are there places of articulation that don't directly develop into different places of articulation?

Comment: Rhotic consonants spring to my mind. See e.g. [Chabot (2019)](https://www.glossa-journal.org/articles/10.5334/gjgl.618/).

Comment: About every sound change is possible and that includes fairly unintuitive changes. The glottal stop is possibly a sound that can hardly change into something else. A regards your specific question, see Japanese hu > fu.

Comment: The glottal stop phoneme is frequently pronounced as a [j] or [w] in Salishan languages, as well as other sounds. It is commonplace for a sound change to simply lose some allophones of a phoneme and retain others (like English /h/ losing [x]).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the subculture of constructed-language enthusiasts, there's an acronym ANADEW: "whatever you proposed for your conlang, A Natlang Already Did it Except Weirder". In other words, pretty much any bizarre sound change you propose has a precedent *somewhere*.

For your specific case, a series of shifts like `ʕ → ʔ → h → ɸ` in certain environments is absolutely possible; while I don't think any language has actually gone through this exact pattern, each of the individual stages is well-attested.